# change date locale in template Keystone.js

Tags: twig, momentjs, keystonejs

I'm using keystone.js with twig.js as template language. how can i change locale in date?
http://keystonejs.com/docs/database/#fieldtypes-date
I looked through all issues and stackoverflow questions and didn't find answer. in my template i write
`{{ post._.publishedDate.format('D MMMM') }}` and output is `9 July`. I want it to be `9 июля` in russian locale.
As far as I know, KeystoneJS use moment.js to set format on date. But how can i change momentjs locale? should i do this on my template or keystone.js or somewhere in middleware or keystone.js file?

I have tried this:

```
{{ post._.publishedDate.locale('ru').format('D MMMM') }}
{{ post.publishedDate.locale('ru').format('D MMMM') }}
{{ post._.publishedDate.format('D MMMM', 'ru') }}
{{ post._.publishedDate.format('D MMMM', 'ru') }}
{{ post.publishedDate.parse('Do MMM YYYY') }}
{{ _.format(post.publishedDate, 'D MMM') }}
```

Also i tried in `keystone.js` file set local variable `moment = require('moment')` and then in template

```
{{ moment(post.publishedDate).locale('ru').format('D MMMM') }}
```

And it didn't work too. What I'm doing wrong?

I can't understand how KeystoneJS work with momentjss and what should I do.
[this documentation part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/os5Gc.png) is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can set default language for whole site as.

```
// keystone.js
var moment = require('moment');
moment.locale(locale);
```

Comment: God damn, that was easy. Thank you for advice!

Comment: I have given two suggestion which one worked for you? can you edit my answer accordingly.?

Comment: oh, sorry I just saw your question. I set default language for whole site in keystone.js file.